# MySQL PHPMYADMIN doesn't return correct result

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I need some help, I ran this SQL query in phpmyadmin, it finds no matching row, but there is a matching row.
I got 12 fields in my table `Users`.

With Other fields match, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE Firstname='John'
```

But with this field `Email` ,no matching row but there is a matching one.

```
SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE Email='afaffas@fdddddg.com'
```

Comment: Please show us your table (definition and data)

Comment: can you please append you table records in your question?

Comment: And what about `trim(Email)='afaffas@fdddddg.com'`

Comment: Are sure sure that you are writting the right email? for example, not putting one more 'a' or 'd' in the email so i won't match? Also, whats the structure of your table, is the email field  varchar?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your not specifying that you going to query another column in the MySQL DB. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE Firstname = 'John' AND Email = 'afaffas@fdddddg.com'
```